# There exist $x_1, x_2, x_3$ such that $\frac{1}{f'(x_1)} + \frac{1}{f'(x_2)} + \frac{1}{f'(x_3)} = 3$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined in $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, with
$f(a) = a, f(b) = b$. Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. Show that there exist three distinct points $x_1, x_2, x_3$ such that

$$\frac{1}{f'(x_1)} + \frac{1}{f'(x_2)} + \frac{1}{f'(x_3)} = 3$$

My hunch is to use the mean-value theorem or Rolle's theorem somehow. But these theorems only guarantee the existence of a certain point, and not a triple of points, so I am stuck.

Comment: Closely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18674/frac1fx-1-frac1fx-2-2?rq=1

Comment: Here is what I have tried. Maybe you can make it work out. Mean value theorem gives you a $x_1\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x_1)=1$. Now for other two points: wlog little to left of $x_1$ slope is little less than one and a little to the right the slope is a little more than one.

Comment: @gnometorule constant function does not fit your hypothesis about $a$ and $b$.  Ian's comment answers your question.

Comment: @johnw. I think his point was that $f'$, not $f$, could be constant, but in that case the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ with $z_1<z_2$ be such that

$$f(z_1)=\frac{2a+b}{3}$$ and 
$$f(z_2)=\frac{a+2b}{3}$$

Then it is easy to see that the slopes formed by the segements 
$$(a,a), (z_1,f(z_1)), (z_2,f(z_2)),  (b,b)$$ sum in their reciprocals to $3$.

Namely,

$$\left(\frac{\frac{b-a}{3}}{z_1-a}\right)^{-1}+
\left(\frac{\frac{b-a}{3}}{z_2-z_1}\right)^{-1}+
\left(\frac{\frac{b-a}{3}}{b-z_2}\right)^{-1}=3
$$
This the gives the points $x_1 \in (a,z_1)$ $x_2 \in (z_1,z_2)$ $x_3 \in (z_2,b)$ by the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x_1)=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=1$$

If that is true then we can simplyfy the task to:

$$\frac{1}{f'(x_2)}+\frac{1}{f'(x_3)}=2$$

For which there already is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18674/frac1fx-1-frac1fx-2-2)